# Display an image from a json format Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I try to render an image with a json format in my view, I store the .json file and try this
my controller :

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  require 'json'

  def index
    file = File.open "app/assets/javascripts/economie.json"
    @data = JSON.load file

  end
end
```

Also my view :

```
 <%= image_tag(@data ) %>
```

I have the error : `Nil location provided. Can't build URI.`

and `<%= @data %>` is displaying the json file not the picture that the json is supposed to be

Anyone having an idea how to fix it ?(I can't display the json file here because it's too long)

Comment: Image in json format? Wot? Most image formats like jpg, gif and png are binary. SVG is XML based. To send any of those through JSON you have to base64 encode the file into a string and then decode it on the other end.

Comment: How does the content of `app/assets/javascripts/economie.json` look like? Is it a binary file? Or does it contain a path to an image?

Answer (score 0):

Not Good Idea to send Image as JSON.
Please do check, how image such as JPEG is stored
[JPEG wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG)

**Best Solution**

1. Upload Image in some cloud server such as CloudFare or Amazon S3
   etc.After image uploaded you can send URL of image from json.

**Rails 6 uses active storage do check it once**

**Not Recommended Approach**

1. To focus on question , I have not tried, but the hackish way would be
   send all raw contents of image file and file extension. After that
   you can reconstruct file again with content and extension received
   from API